# Magento 2 - Update multiple products programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, api

I'm trying to update products programmatically but I got only first product from array updated. All of products in array have status "2" (disabled) in DB. I'm using `$this->productRepositoryInterface` - it's `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`

```
$productSkus = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'];

foreach ($productSkus as $sku) {
    $productToSave = $this->productRepositoryInterface->get($sku);
    echo "Product {$productToSave->getId()} is loaded and ready to update".PHP_EOL;
    $productToSave->setStatus(1);
    $this->productRepositoryInterface->save($productToSave);
}
```

After that code executed - I got only A1 set to "Enabled". Other products keeping be disabled. Echo says it's loading everytime new product to be updated. Magento 2.2.4 EE (CE is also affected)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_product;

 public function __construct(
    .................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    .................
)
{
    .................    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_product = $product;
    .................
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $value) {
        $product = $this->_product->load($value->getId());
        $product->setStatus(1);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Remove var and generated folder.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get productCollection with all products. Then you run a loop for every product and check a condition. This condition should decide if you need to activate or deactivate a product. This can be anything, I used a active product attribute.

```
$productIdsActivate = [];
$productIdsDeactivate = [];

foreach($this->productCollection as $product)
{
    ...
    if($product->getActivate()) {
        $productIdsActivate[] = $product->getId();
    } else {
        $productIdsDeactivate[] = $product->getId();
    }
}

$storeIds = array_keys($this->storeManager->getStores());

//activate products
$updateAttributes['status'] = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED;
foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
    $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIdsActivate, $updateAttributes, $storeId);
}
```

For more reference [click here](https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-change-product-status-programmatically/)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: But how to i can write my SKU number is this code ? In this $productIdsActivate = [];

Comment: Hello, I am trying to update description with html tag and getting array to string conversation error.